# 2 colors + different weight on one element using spans

Tags: sifr

trying to get the span to use the lighter weigth and be a different color

sIFR.replace(xxx, {
  selector: 'h1#logo',
  css: [
      '.sIFR-root { font-size:44px; font-weight:Bold; font-family : Gotham Bold;  color:#17140c; letter-spacing:-2; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0 !important;'
      ]

,filters: {
        DropShadow: {
           distance: 1
          ,color: '#f5f5f5'
          ,strength: 2
          ,alpha: .5
          ,blurX: 0
          ,blurY: 0

```
    }
  }
```

,wmode: 'transparent'
});

sIFR.replace(xxx, {
  selector: 'h1#logo span.thin',
  css: [
      '.sIFR-root { font-size:14px;  font-family : Gotham Light  !important;  color:#ddd; letter-spacing:-2; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0 !important;'
      ]

,filters: {
        DropShadow: {
           distance: 1
          ,color: '#f5f5f5'
          ,strength: 2
          ,alpha: .5
          ,blurX: 0
          ,blurY: 0

```
    }
  }
```

,wmode: 'transparent'
});

Answer (score 0):

The first replacement already replaces the entire `<h1>`. Put in a new CSS selector within the `css` argument to `sIFR.replace()` for `.thin` that has the Light font family.